# Sharepoint template bug, workflow fix not working

Tags: 2007, workflow

I downloaded Microsoft's Employee Training Schedule and Materials template and installed it. Everything works as I need it to except for one bug, which seems to be well documented. When you register for a course the amount of filled seats increases by 1. When you unregister, it should decrease by 1 but doesn't.

I followed the workaround http://paulgalvinsoldblog.wordpress.com/2007/10/11/employee-training-schedule-and-materials-template-decrement-bug-in-the-template/ to try to fix it, but it doesn't decrement the seats either. I also tried a slightly different workaround, but still no joy.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Ok I put a few log messages into the workflow to determine the problem. Here is the workflow as it looks now:

[image]

And how the history reports it:

[image]

So You can see that `Variable:calc` is originally set to 0. And `Courses:Filled Seats` doesn't seem to be getting set. So I can only assume this is a problem with the lookup. This lookup for `Courses:Filled Seats` looks like:

[image]

And the lookup for `Registrations:Course ID` looks like:

[image]

Is there anything there that people can see that might be causing the problem?

Comment: Hi. Couldn't it be a permissions issue? Try checking the permissions for the hidden Workflows list, they're not inherited and users could simply fail to launch the decrement workflow.

Comment: No the workflow is launching, as everything else in it is being performed correctly.

Comment: Run the step in the workflow with impersonation to get around the permission issue.

Comment: Using MOSS 2007 so impersonation isn't an option. But How can it be a permission issue when the rest of the workflow works correctly?

Comment: Do you say that the Workflow Status column is Completed on the items that trigger the workflow? I would suggest logging the calculated value to history and try to catch any edit conflict that could arise.

Comment: Please check the edit above.

Comment: Hey, looks like you're trying to write -1 as 'seats available' to the list. Check the field's settings, maybe there's 0 set as the minimum for numeric value that would prevent the item from being updated successfully. Try adding an action that sets Variable:calc to the maximum of 0 and Variable:calc so that there would never be less than zero seats. Also it seems that the workflow cannot read the actual value of the 'seats available'. Make sure the variable type is suitable for the task at hand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to get the [linked work-around](http://paulgalvinsoldblog.wordpress.com/2007/10/11/employee-training-schedule-and-materials-template-decrement-bug-in-the-template/) working without issue.  So I would guess a step was either missed or done just slightly wrong in following those instructions.  So I will go back through them and highlight potential tricky spots:

- Using SharePoint Designer 2007, open your Training site
- Expand Workflows > Attendee unregistration and double click Attendee unregistration to edit the workflow
- Under Actions, choose **Do Calculation**
- Click the first *value* link and then the [image: fx] button
- Change Source to **Courses**
- Set Field: (In Lookup Details) to **Filled Seats**
- Set Field: (In Find the List Item) to **Courses:ID**
- Click the [image: fx] button next to the Value: text box and choose Source: **Current Item** and Field: **Course ID**

[image: Find List Item Value]

- Your value lookup should now look like this:
  [image]
- Back on the Do Calculation step click the underlined *plus* and change to **minus**
- Click on the second *value* link and type 1 in the textbox
- Under Actions, Choose **Update List Item**
- Click on the *this list* link
- Change the List: to **Courses**
- Click the **Add...** button
- Set field: to **Filled Seats**
- Press the [image: fx] button next to the value: text box
- Choose Source: **Workflow Data** and Field: **Variable: calc** (or whichever variable you stored the Do Calculation action in)

[image]

- In the Find List Item section set Field: to **Courses:ID**
- Click the [image: fx] button next to the Value: text box
- Leave Source as **Current Item** and set Field: to **Course ID**
- Your Update List Item window should now look like this:

[image]

- VERY IMPORTANT: Hover over each action and in the dropdown menu that appears choose **Move Action Up**. Do this until the second action in the list is your Do Calculation action and the third is the Update List Item action.  Your workflow should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Don't know how I missed this from 10 days ago! This is exactly how I have things laid out and it still doesn't work. :( I have +1 you just for the time and effort with the layout and pictures. If you have any other ideas I'd love to hear them.

Comment: By the way, try to add some logging in-between to see where the workflow fails.

Comment: @anothershrubery As a side note, answering this question led to an interesting issue the details of which can be found on Meta here: [Mysterious Butt](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89734/155940). The craziness of that made answering this totally worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out:
http://sptrainingtemplate.codeplex.com/

This issue has been fixed by them you can install this template.

Comment: Ha! I installed that and I'm getting even worse problems! 1) The Total Seats doesn't decrease when you register for the course  and 2) When you unregister, you actually don't! You can't seem to unregister even though it says that you have.

Comment: I can't even seem to open the workflow for Attendee Registration or Attendee Unregistration, it says "Failed to load workflow." I can open the Instructor Reminder workflow though.

Answer (score 2):

Ok another "D'oh" moment from me. I *WAS* doing the lookup wrong as I expected.

I had the `Registration:Course ID` as

[image]

When it should have simply been

[image]

Everything is now working correctly.

No documentation anywhere described how to set the list item in "Find the List Item" and being new to SharePoint I was confused. Eventually worked it out though.

Comment: Nice to have the problem solved. Was it your own bug or that of the application template authors?

Comment: It was my own bug. I didn't know how to create the lookup correctly...

Comment: I'm glad your problem is solved. Unfortunately, I'm guessing you never actually reviewed/tried my answer since I described how to correctly set the lookup and included an actual screenshot similar to the one you are showing above a full two weeks prior to this answer. I spent quite a bit of time on my answer so it's frustrating to know it was dismissed without serious review. However, my end goal was to help solve your issue, and since your issue has been resolved, regardless of how, I'm glad.

Comment: @theChrisKent - I'm sorry, I looked over your answer over and over again and thougth I was copying it to a tee, but just always seemed to miss this lookup issue. I don't know how I missed it! I have now marked your answer as the correct one. Sorry for the annoyance.